# EFI GRUB: Grub not shown after windows 10 boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I'm so exhausted trying to solve my problem.

Steps:

1. After having installed ubuntu, grub menu is shown, and I'm able to select ubuntu.
2. After having gone on ubuntu I restart computer, and then grub menu is shown again.
3. Then, I select on Windows 10. And I restart computer again.
4. After that, grub menu is not shown again, and windows 10 is boot straight.

I've tried to fix this, performing `efibootmgr` on ubuntu live.
The output is something like that:

```
BootCurrent: 0000
0000 Windows Boot Manager
0001 ubuntu
```

After that I perform `efibootmgr -o 0001,0002`.

So, grub menu is shown again, but once I select Windows 10 again, and I restart computer windows 10 is boot straightforwardly.

This is `efibootmgr -v` output:

```
BootCurrent: 000B
Timeout: 0 seconds
BootOrder: 0000,0004,0001,0005,0006,000B,0002,0007,0008,0009,000A,0003
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(2,GPT,4ff9e8db-b517-43ac-9024-364e9bfb2c05,0x109000,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...I................
Boot0001* USB Floppy/CD VenMedia(b6fef66f-1495-4584-a836-3492d1984a8d,0500000001)..BO
Boot0002* USB Hard Drive    VenMedia(b6fef66f-1495-4584-a836-3492d1984a8d,0200000001)..BO
Boot0003* ubuntu    VenHw(99e275e7-75a0-4b37-a2e6-c5385e6c00cb)
Boot0004* USB Floppy/CD VenMedia(b6fef66f-1495-4584-a836-3492d1984a8d,0500000001)..BO
Boot0005* ATAPI CD-ROM Drive    VenMedia(b6fef66f-1495-4584-a836-3492d1984a8d,0300000001)..BO
Boot0006* USB Hard Drive    VenMedia(b6fef66f-1495-4584-a836-3492d1984a8d,0200000001)..BO
Boot0007* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)..GO..NO........O.h.p. . . . . . . .C.D.D.V.D.W. .S.N.-.2.0.8.F.B.................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.1.S.P.1.Y.6.F.B.0.C.8.1.W.K. . . . . . ........BO
Boot0008* USB Floppy/CD VenMedia(b6fef66f-1495-4584-a836-3492d1984a8d,0500000000)..BO
Boot0009* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........W.K.i.n.g.s.t.o.n.D.a.t.a.T.r.a.v.e.l.e.r. .2...0.1...0.0.................F..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.0.0.1.4.7.8.0.C.9.E.D.2.5.A.8.9.1.0.0.C.0.0.1.2........BO..NO........O.W.D.C. . .W.D.S.1.0.0.T.2.B.0.A.-.0.0.S.M.5.0.................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.9.1.9.0.C.6.0.8.0.4.5.8. . . . . . . . ........BO..NO........O.S.T.1.0.0.0.D.M.0.0.3.-.1.E.R.1.6.2.................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.4.Z.5.Y.A.H.3.H. . . . . . . . . . . . ........BO
Boot000A* Realtek PXE B02 D00   BBS(Network,,0x0)..BO
Boot000B* UEFI: KingstonDataTraveler 2.01.00    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1a,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,MBR,0xbe6bfc,0x800,0x1e0b800)..BO
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What brand/model system. Some do not respect efibootmgr and only work with changes from within UEFI. Others only will let you set fallback or hard drive boot entry as first. Grub install makes /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi a copy of shimx64.efi to boot Ubuntu from fallback UEFI boot entry.

Comment: I don't quite understant what do you mean... My Pc is a HP DeskJet 490 pro. What's `within UEFI`?

Comment: That is your printer. Within UEFI is to boot into UEFI, not UEFI boot menu. From inside UEFI you have multiple tabs, typically one is boot and from there you can adjust boot order. Sometimes a submenu & you have to click on UEFI boot devices. HP often requires escape key then key to get into UEFI/BIOS to change settings. UEFI/BIOS Boot keys - about halfway down on this Microsoft page
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12911.tips-for-configuring-your-bios-settings-to-work-with-windows-to-go.aspx

Comment: I've changed boot order into BIOS. Then grub is shown. However, once I select windows option, order is modified!!!! and windows is loaded again straightforwardly. The behavior is something like windows is changing something each time it's loaded...

Comment: Some with HP, said an UEFI update fixed some issues. Do you have latest UEFI from HP for your system?  Also some HP, would let you change boot to the fallback or hard drive boot entry. Grub installs shimx64.efi as /EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi. That was originally just a copy of Windows boot file. If you have a drive UEFI boot entry does it work?

Comment: Yes, it works. I mean, I created an UEFI USB with my ubuntu ready to install it. When it's plugged grub menu is shown with my options (ubuntu and windows...) When it's removed, grub is not shown and windows is started straightforwardly.... Any ideas?

Comment: Is then your only Ubuntu UEFI entry on flash drive, not on internal drive? Post this above to maintain formatting: `sudo efibootmgr -v`

Comment: I've added command output on post.

Comment: That does not look like Ubuntu is installed in UEFI boot mode. Grub only can boot other systems installed in same boot mode. You can boot installer in UEFI boot mode and use Boot-Repair to totally reinstall grub from advanced options to convert install to UEFI.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair How you boot install media UEFI or CSM/BIOS is then how it installs. Shows installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI

Answer (score 0):

Set the windows entry inactive. Make sure windows is complete and remove faststart from windows.

```
sudo efibootmgr --bootnum 0000 --inactive
```

and try again.

Comment: I've tried your approach. After having applied the command above, grub menu is shown again. Nevertheless, after having select windows option, next restarting windows is loaded straightforwardly again.